# Loop within RMarkdown code block

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have a document that's something like this:

````
```{r, include = F}
require(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  A = c(1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 8),
  B = c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5)
)
```


```{r, echo = F}
col <- "A"

knitr::asis_output(paste0("### Column ", col, "\n"))

knitr::asis_output("Counts\n")

dt[, .(n = .N), by = col]

knitr::asis_output("Statistics\n")

summary(dt[, get(col)])
```


```{r, echo = F}
col <- "B"

knitr::asis_output(paste0("### Column ", col, "\n"))

knitr::asis_output("Counts\n")

dt[, .(n = .N), by = col]

knitr::asis_output("Statistics\n")

summary(dt[, get(col)])
```
````

Whilst this works fine, obviously, this is very repetitive. I tried to use a loop rather than the copy-paste, like so:

````
```{r, echo = F}
for (col in c("A", "B")) {
  knitr::asis_output(paste0("### Column ", col, "\n"))

  knitr::asis_output("Counts\n")

  dt[, .(n = .N), by = col]

  knitr::asis_output("Statistics\n")

  summary(dt[, get(col)])
}
```
````

This however prints no output at all. How can I loop in an RMarkdown document and produce both markdown and R output?

Comment: Have you tried `print(summary(dt[, get(col)]))` ?

Comment: Please read the documentation `?knitr::asis_output`. In particular, please do read the Note section. Then you may read https://yihui.name/en/2017/06/top-level-r-expressions/ and https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knit_print.html if you care about technidal details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `print` statement for the `summary` results. Your code would change to the following where only the `print` statement was added to the `summary` output:

````
```{r, echo = F}
for (col in c("A", "B")) {
  print(knitr::asis_output(paste0("### Column ", col)))

  print(knitr::asis_output("Counts"))

  print(dt[, .(n = .N), by = col])

  print(knitr::asis_output("Statistics"))

  print(summary(dt[, get(col)]))
}
```
````

This produces the following results:

```
## [1] "### Column A"
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "knit_asis"
## attr(,"knit_cacheable")
## [1] NA
## [1] "Counts"
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "knit_asis"
## attr(,"knit_cacheable")
## [1] NA
##    A n
## 1: 1 2
## 2: 4 3
## 3: 2 1
## 4: 8 1
## [1] "Statistics"
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "knit_asis"
## attr(,"knit_cacheable")
## [1] NA
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##   1.000   1.500   4.000   3.429   4.000   8.000 
## [1] "### Column B"
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "knit_asis"
## attr(,"knit_cacheable")
## [1] NA
## [1] "Counts"
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "knit_asis"
## attr(,"knit_cacheable")
## [1] NA
##    B n
## 1: 2 2
## 2: 3 2
## 3: 4 1
## 4: 1 1
## 5: 5 1
## [1] "Statistics"
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "knit_asis"
## attr(,"knit_cacheable")
## [1] NA
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##   1.000   2.000   3.000   2.857   3.500   5.000
```

You may want to reformat and remove attributes when printing.

**Edit**

At the suggestion from @user2554330 here is an example using `knitr::knit_print`:

````
```{r, echo = F}
for (col in c("A", "B")) {
  knitr::knit_print(paste0("### Column ", col))
  knitr::knit_print("Counts")
  knitr::knit_print(dt[, .(n = .N), by = col])
  knitr::knit_print("Statistics")
  knitr::knit_print(summary(dt[, get(col)]))
}
```
````

which gives the following output

```
## [1] "### Column A"
## [1] "Counts"
##    A n
## 1: 1 2
## 2: 4 3
## 3: 2 1
## 4: 8 1
## [1] "Statistics"
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##   1.000   1.500   4.000   3.429   4.000   8.000 
## [1] "### Column B"
## [1] "Counts"
##    B n
## 1: 2 2
## 2: 3 2
## 3: 4 1
## 4: 1 1
## 5: 5 1
## [1] "Statistics"
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##   1.000   2.000   3.000   2.857   3.500   5.000
```

**Edit 2**

The following alternate solution will more closely print what the SO is asking for.  It removes the "## " prefix globally and adds it back in for the `data.frame` (i.e. only where needed). It also uses `cat` in place of `knitr::knit_print` to avoid printing the array indexes (i.e. `[1]`).

````
```{r, echo = F, comment=NA}
for (col in c("A", "B")) {
  cat(paste0("Column ", col), "\n")
  cat("Counts\n")
  ## Add comment prefix
  tdf <- as.data.frame(dt[, .(n = .N), by = col]) ## Convert to data.frame for printing
  rownames(tdf) <- paste("## ", 1:nrow(tdf))      ## Add comments for printing.
  knitr::knit_print(tdf)
  cat("Statistics\n")
  ## Add comment prefix
  knitr::knit_print(summary(dt[, get(col)]))
}
```
````

The output below is more of what the SO is asking for (based on comments to this post).  It prefixes the `data.frame` output with "## " but the summary output does not have the "## " prefix; this can be added if needed.

```
Column A 
Counts
      A n
##  1 1 2
##  2 4 3
##  3 2 1
##  4 8 1
Statistics
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.500   4.000   3.429   4.000   8.000 
Column B 
Counts
      B n
##  1 2 2
##  2 3 2
##  3 4 1
##  4 1 1
##  5 5 1
Statistics
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   2.000   3.000   2.857   3.500   5.000
```

Comment: You would also wrap the `knitr::asis_output()` calls and `dt[...]` in `print()` to get those parts to print.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks for catching that the print statements needed to be added for the other rows as well.  I also removed the "\n" as they don't do anything in this case.

Comment: Actually, `knitr::knit_print()` would be better than `print()`.

Comment: @user2554330 I added the solution with `knitr::knit_print()`.  This should be closer to what you are thinking.

Comment: Thanks @steveb, with the `knit_print` calls I actually get some output. However it's formatted very differently from the unlooped version. See comparison in PDF here: https://gist.github.com/thomasfedb/f6d8d5dc9ba4558dd1eafa867715a0a5 Any further tips?

Comment: @thomasfedb I don't have time to dig into this at the moment but the thing that comes to mind is that there are likely `knitr` options that will turn off things like the `[1]` prefix to a line.  I know there is a way to turn off the `## ` prefix for output.  I would start looking at `knitr` options.

Comment: This got half way there, so I'll mark as accepted. Haven't quite managed to get the output I really wanted however.

Comment: @thomasfedb I am short on time but will try to get back to this when I can. It would be good to have a complete answer.

Comment: @thomasfedb Is the item in **Edit 2** what you are looking for ?

Comment: Hey @steveb, it certainly gets us closer, but I'm still unable to get knitr to interpret markdown correctly to make headers/etc in the output. Perhaphs I should preprocess my .Rmd file.

Comment: @thomasfedb Just a clarification, are you referring to being able to print in bold or use the various header types of markdown ?

Comment: @steveb The ability to print headings using the markdown syntax is important. Also important is outputting the tabular data in a format that can be either rendered to PDF, or displayed as an HTML table in the Rmd notebook.

Comment: @thomasfedb I made some progress on this by setting the chunk options.  If I can't figure out the rest, I will at least have a question for SO that, if answered, should address the last bit.